# Sum of poisson random variables

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $N, X_1, \dots , X_n$ be independent random variables.

$N \sim P(\lambda) \quad (\text{Poisson distribution})$, while $X_k \sim B(p)$ (Bernoulli)

Let us consider the "random" sum $S = X_1 + \dots + X_N$, which is random also because of the index $N$

(e.g. if $N=0$ then $ S = 0$, if $N = 3$ then $ S = X_1 + X_2 + X_3$, and so forth)

**Question 1 (theoretical question)**

How do I prove that $S$ and $N - S$ are random variables?

**Question 2 (more pratical)**

I've determined that $S \sim P(\lambda p)$.
How do I calculate the distribution of $N - S$?
They are both Poisson, but they are not independent (it suffice to notice that $N=0 \implies S = 0$)

What I've tried is: 
$$P(N-S = k) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty P(S=j)\cdot P(N=j+k)$$

But I got stuck at
$$P(N-S = k) = e^{-\lambda (p+1)} \lambda^k \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\lambda^2p\right)^j}{j!(\ j+k)!}$$

I don't know how to simplify that. And I'm not even that sure that the way I'm doing is right.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Note that $N - S = \sum_{k=1}^{N} (1-X_k)$ and that $1-X_k \sim B(1-p)$, hence $N-S \sim \mathrm{Poi}(\lambda (1-p))$.

Comment: Actually S and N-S *are* independent.

Comment: @Sasha brilliant! I would be very grateful if could expand that into an answer, maybe addressing also the first problem! :-)

Comment: @Did Yes, but to use the fact that the sum of poisson is poisson I have to use independence on $N$ and $S$, to conclude that also $N-S$ is poisson, right?

Comment: Sorry but S and N are **not** independent.

Comment: @Did Yes I know, I've written that in the question. That is why I'm trying to solve it with that summation instead of just saying that sum of independent poisson is a poisson. On the other hand, kknowing that $S$ and $N-S$ are independent does not help, does it? (by the way, how can one quickly see that $S$ and $N-S$ are independent? )

Comment: Quote: "I have to use independence on N and S". To quickly see that S and N-S are independent, one can compute P(S=i,N=i+j) and watch the miraculous factorization happen.

Comment: I believe I posted an answer to these questions when someone else posted them a few months ago.